# Visual studio code goto matching bracket from bottom to top

Tags: visual-studio-code

I know there is a shortcut for `cmd + shift + \` to go to matching bracket

this is also documented here https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-macos.pdf

But this only works when the cursor is at the opening bracket and you want to jump at closing bracket.  So its not really matching...its actually closing.

But if you have a class like

```
object Foo {
....
}
```

and you take the cursor to the closing bracket and now you press `cmd + shift + \` then vscode does nothing.

So it only works from opening to closing .... but how to go from closing to opening?

Similarly, when you take the cursor to the opening bracket, visual studio code will highlight the closing bracket. but if you take the cursor to the closing bracket, vscode will do nothing. now it will not highlight the opening bracket.

How can I have it both ways.

Comment: Not quite what you're looking for but using an extension like Bracket Pair Colorizer or Rainbow Brackets helps keep track of matching brackets.

Comment: Now it works both ways, meaning the keyboard shortcut `cmd + shift + \ ` (or `cmd + shift + \ `  in ubuntu) will toggles between open and close braces.

Comment: Thanks @nick, for clarification the Bracket Pair Colorizer not only colors all brackets, parenthesis, etc. but if you place the cursor inside a bracket (like next to the very beginning or end) it will draw an enclosing line around the area/function where the code inside that bracket is contained. So if some of your brackets don't match up, you'll see which one it is. The Rainbow Brackets only colors all the brackets, parens, etc.

Answer (score 28):

As of the latest version of Visual Studio Code, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>\</kbd> **toggles between both the opening and closing brackets** of a code block.

I personally find the default key binding a bit awkward, so I remapped it to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>\</kbd> by going to `File > Preferences > Settings`, clicking the curly braces icon to edit the `settings.json` file directly, and adding the following code inside of the square brackets:

```
{ 
    "key": "ctrl+alt+oem_5",
    "command": "editor.action.jumpToBracket",
    "when": "editorTextFocus" 
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio Code now has a UI for keyboard shortcut mappings.

- The default way to get there by keystroke is:

  ```
  Ctrl+K, Ctrl+S
  ```
- To get there via the UI:

  1. Click the gear
  2. Click *Keyboard Shortcuts*
- To get there via the vscode command menu, search for *Keyboard
  Shortcuts*